# How to custom v-for using v-if for make a class in div tag

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

How to correctly way use v-if when I using v-for inside?

Actually I want to add a condition when the index is `0` or `first data` is displayed I want to add `active class`

```
<div class="item active" v-for="(item, key, index) in slideItem" :key="item._id">
    <img alt="900x500" src="http://lorempixel.com/960/720/">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
        <p>{{ item.body }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and show this when the next data :

```
<div class="item" v-for="(item, key, index) in slideItem" :key="item._id">
        <img alt="900x500" src="http://lorempixel.com/960/720/">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ item.body }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You can see the two examples I gave, how I combine the two loops into one by distinguishing the first index (`item active)` condition and so on using `v-if`

Comment: Is `slideItem` an array or an object?

Comment: Hi @RossWilson is Object

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function `isActive` that determines if the index is at 0 and than

```
v-bind:class="{'active': isActive}"
```

Comment: Hi @dscni Do I have to create a function and how does it distinguish it? I just started vue

Comment: yes, you should create `isActive` function. You should put it in either mounted cycle or methods and than call it if you're waiting on data

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.. I Think you are using a key, for an array...  the key is used for a dictionary.
Here is how it works:

CSS

```
.active {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="output">
 <div class="item" v-for="(item, index) in slideItem" :key="item._id">
   <div class="carousel-caption"  :class="{active: index==1}">
     <h3>{{ item.title }} {{index}}</h3>
     <p>{{ item.body }}</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Notice that I removed the key!

JS:

```
var vm = new Vue({
 el: "#output",
 data: function () {
   return {
     slideItem : [
     {  '_id' :0, 'title':'title0' ,'body':'body 0'},
     {  '_id' :1, 'title':'title1' ,'body':'body 1'},
     {  '_id' :2, 'title':'title2' ,'body':'body 2'},
     {  '_id' :3, 'title':'title3' ,'body':'body 3'},
     {  '_id' :4, 'title':'title4' ,'body':'body 4'},
     {  '_id' :5, 'title':'title5' ,'body':'body 5'}
     ]
     }
   }
  });
```

What ...
Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unsbunzn/1/)

Comment: Hi @CodeHacker Do I have to create a function like what `dscni` says?

Comment: Not at all... if you do more than 1 line you should, but for something as easy as that ... just write the condition there

Comment: Must use `item.index===0`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
<div class="item" v-for="(item, k) in slideItem" :key="item._id"
     :class="{active: Object.keys(slideItem)[0] == k}">
    <img alt="900x500" src="http://lorempixel.com/960/720/">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
        <p>{{ item.body }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

`Object.keys(slideItem)[0] == k` gets the first key of the object and then checks that the key for current iteration matches.